# YouCompleteMe considers underscore as word character

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me

YouCompleteMe considers underscores `_` as word characters, which is desirable in most programming languages. But in TeX and LaTeX, this is not the case, especially where the underscore has a reserved marker for subscripts.

What I want is to remove underscores as word characters, so that it does not recognise constructions like `alpha_` or `sum_` as words.

**How can a disable `_` as a word character?**

---

A MWE (I use Neovim wiht `vim-plug`):

```
" ~/.config/nvim/init.vim file
call plug#begin('~/.local/share/nvim/plugged')
  Plug 'sirver/ultisnips'
  Plug 'ycm-core/YouCompleteMe'
call plug#end()
```

```
# custom snippet file
snippet _ "subscript" iA
_{$1}
endsnippet
```

```latex
% main `main.tex` file
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  $\sum_{n}$
  $\sum_}$  % <- Here is the problem.
\end{document}
```

In the above problem line, if I type `\sum`, YCM suggests me the word `sum_` for autocompletion. Ignoring that and continue typing `_`, the snippet is not expanded correctly as `_{}`, but `_}`, where the cursor lies just before `}`. <s>Notice that this happens only for the second and subsequent `\sum`s.</s>

**Edit:** This happens for any word followed by an underscore, if that word previously appeared in the code and YMC parsed it. So this produces the same problem:

```
Hi
Hi_}  % <- Same problem
```

Comment: You should check [`:h 'iskeyword'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27iskeyword%27). Also I'm fairly sure we have a duplicate of this question but I can't find it right now.

Comment: @statox Yeah, `:verbose set isk?` returns `@,48-57,_,192-255`, last set by the plugin `vimtex`. Do you think that changing this will fix the problem, e.g. by `let g:tex_isk='@,48-57,192-255`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @statox mentioned in the comments, setting `iskeyword` solves the problem.

---

For those who want a specific solution:

It is a good practice to write filetype plugins for every filetype you use (in this case, `.tex` files), it keeps your `init.vim` file clean and tidy. Add the following line into your `~/.config/nvim/ftplugin/tex.vim` file:

```
setlocal iskeyword=@,48-57,192-255
```

Comment: For what it's worth you could even use `set local iskeyword-=_` this way you only remove `_` and keep the other settings